# Using Partition By in an inner join to return a single value

Tags: sql

I have read a table and it returned a value. I now need to do an Inner Join with another table to get the next highest value available after this value in this Table.

I.e I have just returned the value 7 from a select and the Table I now need to join with contains the values;
1
5
7
11
20
I only want to return 11 in my join.

I have tried 'Row_Number () Over Partition By' but doesn't work for me because I am using an 'on (A.Number > B.Number) in the Join statement so the Row Number returned will not always be 1 for me.

Any advice?

I tried something like this;

```
SELECT a_number_field

    FROM Table_A A

         INNER JOIN (

                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (

                         PARTITION BY another_number_field

                         ORDER BY another_number_field

                     ) rn

                     FROM Table_B

             ) B

             ON (b.another_number_field > a.A_number_field)

    WHERE a.number_field = 7 
and rn=1;
```

I am expecting only the value 11 to be returned to me.

Comment: and what error message or invalid result are you currently getting?

Comment: Subquery B did not include `another_number_field` in the select list, but the outer query tries to use that field as one of the join conditions in the ON clause.

Comment: Thanks Joel, that worked perfectly for me. I never would have thought of taking the row_number out of the actual join.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` with your join query as the following:

```
SELECT a_number_field, another_number_field
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.a_number_field ORDER BY another_number_field) rn FROM
  tableA A JOIN tableB B
  ON B.another_number_field > A.a_number_field
) T
WHERE rn = 1 AND a_number_field = 7
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VTuPHhV_).

Comment: Thanks Joel, that worked perfectly for me. I never would have thought of taking the row_number out of the actual join. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. I need to amend the sql that Joel sent me some months back. In it he showed me how to retrieve the next highest number from a table but I now need to select both the next highest and the previous highest. Again I have read in the number 7 from a query so I'm expecting to retrieve five and 11 from this new query. Any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thanks, Garret.

Comment: Hi, this would be a little complex, do another left join on a reverse condition, use another row_number and then use conditional aggregation to get your values, check this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/-N8jBZED